# UISearchBar results not shown

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I'm using UISearchBar in my app.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope 
{
    [self.filtered removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.companyName contains[cd] %@",searchText];
    NSArray *tempArray = [ee filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    filtered = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
}
```

I did `NSLog` on above "filtered" array, it's getting proper search results.

I don't see the filtered values in the tableview. I see "No results" if I type wrong search text. But for the correct search text, the table view is plain empty.

Can anyone help me what needs to be done?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: check to see if your array is null

Comment: have you reload the tableview. Is Filtered array is datasouece of tableview ?

Comment: My filtered Array is not null, I did NSLog to see the filtered values. I see the filtered array values in cellForRowAtIndexPath method as well and in numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: I have only one reload call inside viewDidLoad. I'm not sure what you mean by Filtered array is datasource? I didn't explicitly said it as datasource. Please let me know how to do it, if I've missed that. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code ?

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellId= @"eCell";
ECell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellId];
if (cell==nil)
{
        cell= [[ECell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    Ex *e;
    if (tableView== self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
   {
        e= [filtered objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }
else
    {
        e= [ee objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    cell.company.text= e.companyName;
    return cell;
}

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem. If the cell is UITableViewCell, the Filter from SearchBar is working. I have a custom cell, in which I've extended the UITableViewCell to ECell. Using this, Filterdata is not working. Any idea?

Comment: Hi user906492, did you solve this issue? I am also using a custom cell and getting empty results.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code . And make sure that `self.filtered`  is the datasource of yourtableview . Datasource means array
 from tableview gets populated

```
 - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope 
    {
        [self.filtered removeAllObjects];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.companyName contains[cd] %@",searchText];
        NSArray *tempArray = [ee filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        filtered = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
   [yourtableview reloadData];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Write the above code  then Reload the table in the source code 


   [tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem. If the cell is UITableViewCell, the Filter from SearchBar is working. I have a custom cell, in which I've extended the UITableViewCell to ECell. Using this, Filterdata is not working. Any idea?

Comment: tableview of object reload